# Why does AlertDiolog.show() produce an error in Android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to build a really simple alert dialog process. I built the dialog so that the only thing it does is to show the alert. But it instead produces an error.

Here is the related code of my project:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Context appContext = getApplicationContext();                                   
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(appContext);                
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");
    alertDialogBuilder
        .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            try {
              HttpResponse response=RestServicesCaller.cancelTransaction(transactionId);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
          }
        });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

If I comment out the `alertDialog.show()` when pressing the button, nothing happens (as expected). But if I open it pressing the button, it forces to close to program. What can cause this?

I think that it may be result from xml maybe...?

Comment: logcat output pls.. ..

Comment: but i think its a context problem .. try a global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the application context but the activity context when creating dialogs, toasts etc.

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
            .setTitle("Your Title")
            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    try {
                        HttpResponse response = RestServicesCaller.cancelTransaction(transactionId);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                 }
             })
             .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
             })
             .show();
    }
});
```

MyActivity would be your activity (if it's a fragment just use getActivity() instead).
BTW AlertDialog.Builder is a builder meaning you can actually use the builder pattern ;-).

There's an excellent article about when to use which context: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer is right https://stackoverflow.com/a/17958395/1326308 and I think that in your case is better to use *dialog.dismiss()* instead of *dialog.cancel()*